# Как добавить метку на карту яндекс?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Использую код из примера https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions_districts/

```
var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [50, 15],
    zoom: 0,
    type: null,
    controls: ['zoomControl']
},{
    restrictMapArea: [[30, -10], [85,-100]]
});
Код метки
// Метка, содержимое балуна которой загружается с помощью AJAX.
placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.8, 37.72], {
    iconContent: "Узнать адрес",
    hintContent: "Перетащите метку и кликните, чтобы узнать адрес"
});
конец метки
map.controls.get('zoomControl').options.set({size: 'small'});
// Добавим заливку цветом.
var pane = new ymaps.pane.StaticPane(map, {
    zIndex: 30, css: {
        width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7'
    }
});
```

Хочу добавить метку, но она не выходить.
Почему метка не добавляется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление метки одной строкой делается не так. Прочитайте [документацию](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark.html), там есть пример.

Либо вы задаёте переменную с параметрами метки (**var placemark = new...**), и затем добавляете этот геообъект на карту (**map.geoObjects.add(placemark)**), либо добавляете объект сразу, передавая ему параметры точки:

```
map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.8, 37.72], {
    iconContent: "Узнать адрес",
    hintContent: "Перетащите метку и кликните, чтобы узнать адрес"
}))
```

Comment: исправил как у тебя, карта вообще пропала

Comment: Проверьте свой код. Вы где-то ошиблись при манипуляциях. Код с единственной правкой по образцу выше прекрасно работает: https://jsfiddle.net/zt2ux5ey/

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.